# dual boot windows 7 home premium and ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, windows, windows-7, 14.04, system-installation

I have a Sony Vaio laptop with 4 GB RAM.It has Windows 7 home premium by default.I want to dual boot it with Ubuntu 14.04.How do I do it?My laptop does not boot Windows properly and shows logon initialization failure error.I cannot use safeboot as it hangs as soon as I select the option.It also cannot detect Wifi,USB,CD/DVD.How can I dual boot it?I also do not have the Windows disk.

Answer (score 0):

1. Just download the image file and write it into a DVD.
2. Then boot the laptop with it and let Ubuntu install on RAM.
3. When virtual desktop comes, It goes to install Ubuntu icon and then click on it.
4. Choose the option `Install Ubuntu with windows side by side`.
5. Follow the instruction like user name, language , time zone, etc.
6. Let it install.
7. After installation, reboot the system.
8. Update the system and use. Enjoy.

Comment: Note though that they said their system doesn't boot Widnows properly. It could well be that doing a side-by-side install will actually fix that, it could make no difference, but in all I'd be less confident a dual boot install was going to go well if the existing OS was showing problems. At the very least, anything important should be backed up first: Installing beside a set-up that isn't running correctly can be a bit like building on sand; even if you do a good job, it can still fall down.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned it cannot detect USB and CD/DVD drive. Is it the Windows that cannot detect these or they aren't detected at all (at BIOS level)?

If it's the latter, then you'd better put the hard drive in another machine & get Ubuntu installed on it, then put the hard drive back in your laptop. Unlike Windows, Ubuntu will still boot up even if the installation is made on a different machine.

Comment: It is Windows that cannot detect this.The BIOS can detect it.But when I use a USB,it says NTLSR missing.What is that?

Comment: I guess you meant NTLDR. If by booting through USB you're getting that error I assume your laptop supports USB boot, it's just that the Live USB is corrupted. There could be 2 reasons here, either the Ubuntu image you're using is corrupted or the Live USB wasn't done properly.

Could you try recreating a Live USB using https://launchpad.net/win32-image-writer, but try re-downloading the Ubuntu ISO image.